# How to NOT apply texture t specific islands?

Tags: texturing, uv, displacement

Context: I modeled a phone stand on Fusion 360 with the purpose of 3d printing it. I want to add texture to the object so it looks like wood.

Here are my steps:

0. Import STL file into Blender
1. Remesh in Voxel mode
2. Select all in the mesh (pressing A)
3. UV -> Smart UV Project (http://is.am/5zwh)
4. Add a displacement modifier
5. Create new texture from an image (for the displacement)
6. Change coordinates to UV and select the created UV Map
7. Set a strength, and then I have a nice object where every face has the surface:

[image]

Say I want this texture to be applied to only some parts of my model. For instance, I don't want the texture to be applied to the base of the object, or to the faces inside the whole.

How do I tell blender not to apply any texture to a set of faces, or to a specific uv mapping island?

Comment: Apart from the abswer given by @moonboots you have to know about materials that you can render objects without any material on and they will show up in this white/light grey. But as soon as you put a material on it, everything will get this as default material. And you can assign materials to certain faces, but once there is a material on the object, the unapplied faces can no longer have no material, they will either show the now new default material or you have to give the object a second material and assign those faces to the second material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *Coordinates > UV* in the *Displace* modifier, then you can either use *Vertex Group* in order to assign the displacement to the vertex group you want only, or don't use vertex group but in that case you need to have the 2 textures into the same image and place the UV island over the correct part of the image.

[image]